# how to split this json data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How to split this json data using javascript? And I want store `content.rendered` json in the different variables are description as first `p` tag, image as second  `p` tag, file as third `p` tag to display it in the html page. Could you please anyone help me on this split?Could you please spilit the each content.rendered from array of json as mentioned in the sippet?

```js
 [{
       "author": 1,
       "content": {
          "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
          "protected": false
       }
    },
    {
       "author": 1,
       "content": {
          "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
          "protected": false
       }
    },
    {
       "author": 1,
       "content": {
          "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
          "protected": false
       }
    }]
```

Comment: How do you want to split the JSON?

Comment: Hi Jh314, I want to have it in the following variables, description="Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!",2.pdf="<a href="file.pdf"></a>",3.image= img src="image.jpg"/>

Comment: You mean `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Have you tried anything or researched how to work with JSON in Javascript?

Comment: You need to help us out a little more, You are showing an object with `author`, `content`, `rendered`, and `protected` and then saying you want `content.description`, `content.image` ,`content.file`. Where do those come from? Are you trying to pull those all out of `content.rendered`?

Comment: That's not JSON at all, which requires strings to be delimited by quotes (`"`)!

Comment: Hi  Mark Meyer,I updated that variable we need to create in the javascript to store the value that is our option.

Comment: Hi All I updated my post Please check I only want to split the content.rendered object in different variables as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to parse the JSON using `JSON.parse` then you'll need to parse the HTML stored in `content.rendered`.

Something like the following should work.

```
const str = `{
   "author": 1,
   "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\\n<p><a href=\\"file.pdf\\"></a></p>\\n<p><img src=\\"image.jpg\\"/></p>",
      "protected": false
   }
}`
let json = JSON.parse(str)
let content = document.createElement('div')
content.innerHTML = json.content.rendered

let description = content.querySelector('p').innerText
let image = content.querySelector('img').src
let file = content.querySelector('a').href

let result = {
  description,
  image,
  file
}
```

Comment: Ikbel can you give it in the jsfiddle if possible or pluker?

Comment: what about the frist p tag description? how your storing in variable?

Comment: @njeoo I have updated the snippet, it's really pretty straightforward, just copy and paste it in your jsfiddle and add some `console.log`s to see what's going on.

Comment: As I said, this should work for the json you provided but it actually depends on the position of the elements `a`, `p` and `img` because `.querySelector` will find the first element that matches the selector. So I'd suggest adding some classes to identify those elements.

Comment: Hi Ikbel,How to split more than one array of object as update above?

Comment: @njeoo you should actually open another question rather than editing this one. Now this answer is no longer relevant to your current question.

Comment: Yes Agree if possible could you split the array of content as i updated above.

Comment: Hi Ikbel,Please check the new question raised.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971393/how-to-split-the-array-of-objects-from-json

Comment: Hi Ikbel,could you please check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975935/using-angular-5-how-to-split-the-array-of-json?noredirect=1#comment90902294_51975935

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want to **parse** data.

Firstly, `JSON.parse()`

Then, you need to parse the `content.rendered` (correct me,pls, if not). For this you can try:

```
let [, data, file, img] = data
  .split('<p>')
  .map(v => v.replace(/<\/p>/g,''));

data = data.trim();
file = file.match(/"(.*?)"/)[0]; // file.pdf
img= img.match(/"(.*?)"/)[0]; // image.jpg
```

Comment: can you give it in the jsfiddle if possible or pluker?