# How to split the array of objects from json?

Tags: javascript

Could you please split the each content.rendered from array of json as mentioned in the sippet?How to split this json data using javascript?How to split this json data using javascript? And I want store content.rendered json in the different variables are description as first p tag, image as second  p tag, file as third p tag to display it in the html page.

```js
const str = `{
   "author": 1,
   "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\\n<p><a href=\\"file.pdf\\"></a></p>\\n<p><img src=\\"image.jpg\\"/></p>",
      "protected": false
   }
}`
let json = JSON.parse(str)
let content = document.createElement('div')
content.innerHTML = json.content.rendered

let description = content.querySelector('p').innerText
let image = content.querySelector('img').src
let file = content.querySelector('a').href

let result = {
  description,
  image,
  file
}
```

```html
 [{
           "author": 1,
           "content": {
              "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
              "protected": false
           }
        },
        {
           "author": 1,
           "content": {
              "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
              "protected": false
           }
        },
        {
           "author": 1,
           "content": {
              "rendered": "<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p>",
              "protected": false
           }
        }]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code that you are having a problem with? Bear in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Hi Abion47,I have tried this please check...if possible help teach me out

Comment: Hello frist see my thing if possible help me out I updated my code above my tried thing.I have tried splited correctly for single object json. If you know help me otherwise don't send unnecessary texts

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop to iterate over the different elements?

Comment: No I have tried but not able to get it..

Comment: How is this different than last time you asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921448/how-to-split-this-json-data-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` on your array.

So based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921448/how-to-split-this-json-data-using-javascript/51921582?noredirect=1#comment90893273_51921582), this is how you can achieve that.

```
const myArray = [
    {
        author: 1,
        content: {
            rendered:
                '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href="file.pdf"></a></p>\n<p><img src="image.jpg"/></p>',
            protected: false
        }
    },
    {
        author: 1,
        content: {
            rendered:
                '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href="file.pdf"></a></p>\n<p><img src="image.jpg"/></p>',
            protected: false
        }
    },
    {
        author: 1,
        content: {
            rendered:
                '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href="file.pdf"></a></p>\n<p><img src="image.jpg"/></p>',
            protected: false
        }
    }
]

const extractData = obj => {
    let content = document.createElement('div')
    content.innerHTML = obj.content.rendered

    let description = content.querySelector('p').innerText
    let image = content.querySelector('img').src
    let file = content.querySelector('a').href

    return {
        description,
        image,
        file
    }
}

const results = myArray.map(extractData)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ikbel.I am very greatful to you.Let us have in touch.Can you share your mail id..

Comment: how to console and see this output? i have tried this below.console.log(results.image);
  console.log(results.description);
  console.log(results.file);
  }

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry but I think we can't share email addresses here.

Comment: you should actually do `results[0].image`

Comment: But Thank you very much.

Comment: @njeoo It sounds like you don't understand what arrays are and how they work. I don't mean to be rude, but you could benefit from taking a step back from the project you are working on and following some programming tutorials.

Comment: if i use this i can access only results[0].image details alone but i want display in the the loop is it possible?

Comment: ok  Abion47 Sure I will look forward to learn the thing if possible can you share the link to go through?

Comment: `[0]` is used to access an array item at the position `0`. You can use a loop to iterate over your array and replace 0 with `i` or something. I think you said you use angular. then check out an example on how to use arrays in an ngFor

Comment: Hi Ikbel,able to display the json hardcoded but i tried in angular but not able to find ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: this is my angular services :                                                                    
   getdata(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.getjsonurl);
  }, this is my component:

Comment: this is my component:                                                      
  data: any;                                                                            
  this.service.getdata()
   .subscribe(data=> this.data = data);
 }

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let dat of data;let i= index;">
                      <th scope="row">{{dat.image}}</th>
                      <td>{{ dat.description }}</td>
                      <td>{{ dat.file }}<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>

Comment: Hi Ikbel can you add this logic here?

Comment: Hi lkbel Suppose the content.rendered description comes second place like how to display the description then.content": {
              "rendered": "<p><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></p><p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n<p><a href=\"file.pdf\"></a></p>\n",
              "protected": false
           }

Comment: Hi Ikbel,this code abosulty works.When there is no image and file  like this <p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it</p>, the error i am getting:item is not defined, src and file is null.Please update